# Django Oracle Insertion

Tags: django, oracle, cx-oracle

My Environment:
Redhat 7
Oracle 12.c
Django 2.1
cx_Oracle 7.1.2

When I tried to insert,create or do python manage.py makemigrations or python manage.py migrate, I get the error :
 'The database did not return a new row id. Probably "ORA-1403: '
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: The database did not return a new row id. Probably "ORA-1403: no data found" was raised internally but was hidden by the Oracle OCI library (see https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/28859).

Can someone please tell me how to fix the problem I'm going crazy here.

Answer (score 0):

This problem persisted in django==2.1 but when I upgraded to django==2.2 the oracle insertion doesnt had any problem. It inserted sucessfully.

Answer (score 0):

This was a known issue what was fixed starting with Django 2.2.

https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/28859